# How to calculate RMSE for two regression lines

Tags: regression, linear-model, measurement-error, mse

I'm struggling on how can I calculate the RMSE for two regressions. Consider the following scenario: I have two linear regressions, and Id like to calculate the joint RMSE for this model.

[image]

Any hint on how can I do that? Maybe just sum the mean square error of all and then compute the root?

Comment: Imagine instead of a linear model you would have a decision tree model, and suppose the decision tree only predicted two possible values - two leaves, the first leaf would contain 10% of the data and would predict the mean of the red points, the second leaf would contain the remaining data and would predict the mean of the blue points. How would you estimate the RMSE in this case?

Comment: @user2974951 would you have to weigh by the sample size?

Comment: No, a regular mean would be used, based on the residuals (squared, absolute, ...).

Comment: It is not clear why you want to calculate the joint RMSE for two different regression lines, and why you are not weighing as the number of blue data points is much larger than the red data points. Can you expand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know how to calculate the residuals (“error” in statistical slang) for the blue line. You know how to do it for the red line.

Now square all of those numbers, add up those squared values, divide by how many total (both colors) values you had, and take the square root.

$$
\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N_{red}} (y_{i, red}-\hat y_{i, red})^2
+
\sum_{j=1}^{N_{blue}} (y_{j, blue}-\hat y_{j, blue})^2}{
N_{red}+N_{blue}
}}
$$

Comment: This was my intuition, would this really be the path to such a calculation? In other words, am I not breaking any mathematical/statistical laws?

Comment: @Ga13 You have true values (points) and predicted values (points on the colored lines at the same X-coordinates as your data). RMSE does not care how you got those predicted values. You can get them from one regression line for both colors, one regression line per color (what you did), fitting a complicated model like a deep neural network, predicting the same $y$ value no matter the $X$, or guessing random values, and you still have the RMSE.

Comment: yes it makes sense to me! thanks for the clarification